# Default type of JOIN used by Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, apache-pig

What is the default type of JOIN used by Hive? I understand that Pig performs a Hash-join by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive supports equi joins by default.

You can optimize your join by using Map-side Join or a Merge Join depending upon the size and sort order of your tables.

Check this post for more details:
[Hadoop's Map-side join implements Hash join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823303/hadoops-map-side-join-implements-hash-join)

For more details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins